# Closing idle connections: Does Sequelize allow me to view how long a DB connection has been idle?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My app server uses a database per tenant and I need to connect to many databases at once. To do so with Sequelize I maintain a db pool where I add a connection to a Map:

```
addConnection(dbKey) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    dbKey,
    "username",
    "password",
    {
      host: localhost,
      port: 5000,
      schema: 'main',
      dialect: 'postgres'
    }
  );

  const models = {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    customerData: CustomerData(sequelize, DataTypes)
  }
  
  this.dbPool.set(dbKey, models);
}
```

This allows me to retrieve sequelize instances as needed. Currently I do not see any support for single sequelize instances managing connections to multiple databases. And because I am maintaining my own Map of connections it seems that I would need to perform the task of releasing idle connections.

I would like to close idle connections and drop them from the Map if they are not used for a certain interval. I have considered a few ways of doing so but do not know which are feasible. It really comes down to 2..

1 - set options.pool.idle for the Sequelize instance.

```
> The maximum time, in milliseconds, that a connection can be idle before being released.
```

AFAIK this does not do what I want, this only sets a timeout when there is a connection pool for the same DB so this clearly won't work.

2 - Use SetInterval to close connections and drop their reference from the Map object when idle.

```
a) When opening connection, set a timestamp along with connection.

b) Whenever the sequelize instance is used to make a query, update the timestamp.

c) Every minute or so, close and free any connections that have been idle for longer than some time period.
```

To do so it would be great if there were some internal field in Sequelize or getter that would let me see when the connection was last used. Looking at the API for the Sequelize and model instances, I do not see such a field or method. Is there a way to determine the time a connection was last used in the Sequelize library?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new Sequelize instance it creates a pool in the background by default.
You can look the `options.pool` object that is available for the instance initialization.
[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-constructor-constructor](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor)  :

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    dbKey,
    "username",
    "password",
    {
        host: localhost,
        port: 5000,
        schema: 'main',
        dialect: 'postgres',
        pool: {
            idle: 10000, // milliseconds
            evict: 20000, // milliseconds
        }
    }
);
```

It has default values as follow:

> public constructor(database: string, username: string, password: string, **options**: object)

| Name | Type | Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| options.pool | object | optional | sequelize connection pool configuration |
| options.pool.max | number | optional, default: 5 | Maximum number of connection in pool |
| options.pool.min | number | optional, default: 0 | Minimum number of connection in pool |
| options.pool.idle | number | optional, default: 10000 | The maximum time, in milliseconds, that a connection can be idle before being released. |
| options.pool.acquire | number | optional, default: 60000 | The maximum time, in milliseconds, that pool will try to get connection before throwing error |
| options.pool.evict | number | optional, default: 1000 | The time interval, in milliseconds, after which sequelize-pool will remove idle connections. |
| options.pool.validate | Function | optional | A function that validates a connection. Called with client. The default function checks that client is an object, and that its state is not disconnected |
| options.pool.maxUses | number | optional, default: Infinity | The number of times a connection can be used before discarding it for a replacement, used for eventual cluster rebalancing. |

Therefore it will automatically release and acquire connections as per the default values above or the values that you provide.

So, lets say there's no query executed for 10000 milliseconds then the connection is released as per default value of `options.pool.idle`.

Therefore when no query is triggered for some time then the sequelize instance is just present there without any live DB connection. So if that's fine you can keep it as it is. Or can use connection hooks below to identify the connection and maintain a counter to initialize/remove Sequelize instances from your Map.

You can look at the connection hooks docs here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#connection-hooks

Comment: Thanks. I am being too picky. I am going to use the idle and evict options unless the Map ever becomes a problem in terms of bloat. I am concerned with having too many instances of Sequelize, I'm not sure how having say 100 or 1000 will effect performance.